# How to communicate between two processes

Tags: c++, concurrency, concurrent-programming

Hi I'm  working on a c++ project that I'm trying to keep OS independent and I have two processes which need to communicate. I was thinking about setting up a 3rd process (possibly as a service?) to coordinate the other two, asynchronously.

Client 1 will tell the intermediate process when data is ready, and send the data to it. The intermediate process will then hold this data until client 2 tells it that it is ready for the data. If the intermediate process has not received new data from client 1, it will tell client 2 to wait.

Since I am trying to keep this OS independent I don't really know what to use. I have looked into using MPI but it doesn't really seem to fit this purpose. I have also looked into Boost.ASIO, Named Pipes, RPC's and RCF. Im currently programming in Windows but I'd like to avoid using the WIN_API so that the code could potentially be compiled in Linux.

Here's a little more detail on the two processes.

We have a back end process/model (client 1) that will receive initial inputs from a GUI (client 2, written in Qt) via the intermediate process. The model will then proceed to work until the end condition is met, sending data to the server as it becomes ready. The GUI will ask the intermediate process for data on regular intervals and will be told to wait if the model has not updated the data. As the data becomes available from the model we also want to be able to keep any previous data from the current session for exporting to a file if the user chooses to do so (i.e., we'll want the GUI to issue a command to the interface to export (or load) the data).

My modification privleges of the the back end/model are minimal, other than to adhere to the design outlined above. I have a decent amount of c++ experience but not much parallel/asynchronous application experience. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On of the purposes of Boost.ASIO is to be platform independent. You can also use sockets directly which is very similar on both Windows and Linux. What problems did you have with all the methods you list?

Comment: Not sure what problems you had with the methods you tried, but it might be worth taking a look at this alternative: [ZeroC Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg We did not have any major problems with any of the listed methods. We are just unsure where to focus our attention since we are unfamiliar with this type of set up. How would one do remote-like calls from one process to another using, for example, Boost.ASIO?

Comment: @Dark: From an engineering perspective, it helps if you clearly choose between an RPC (code) or an I/O (data) model. There are multiple standard ways to map one to the other, but why add unnecessary complexity? With that in mind, it becomes clear why Boost.ASIO doesn't do RPC.

Comment: @MSalters  so, for example, if I use ASIO (or, really, any other data I/O model) for transferring data, what might I use to differentiate between calls to "get data" and "export data"/"load data" ?

Comment: @Dark: For data, the usual differentiators are source and sink identity (where is the data coming from, and where is it going to?). E.g. for file input, the source is a named file and the sink is a particular process.

Answer (score 1):

Standard BSD TCP/IP socket are mostly platform independent. They work with some minor differences on both windows and Unices (like linux).

PS windows does not support AF_UNIX sockets.

Answer (score 1):

I'd checkout the [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) library.  If the two processes are on the same machine it has a number of different ways to communicate between processes, and do so in an platform independent manner.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have considered the messaging system but if you are sending structured data between processes you should consider looking at google protocol buffers.

These related to the content of the messaging (what is passed) rather than how they are passed.

boost::asio is platform independent although it doesn't imply C++ at both ends. Of course, when you are using C++ you can use boost::asio as your form of transport.